# Changing service code for object inside a system in Alloy

Tags: alloy, declarative-programming

I want to change the service code of an object whenever there has been any service operated upon it. Suppose, I have a operation whenever that applies to an object, the service code of that object will be 1 and again when another operation executes then the service code will be 2. I want to save the latest service code to each object. Unfortunately, I am not able design my predicate well, that's why getting predicate inconsistent message from alloy.

I have tried some code for assigning service code to each object. The complete code shown below-

```
open util/ordering[Environment]

abstract sig Object{
    name: String,
    serviceCode: Int,
}{

    serviceCode >= 0 and serviceCode <= 3
}

// Events
enum Event {Event1, Event2, Event3}

abstract sig Condition{
    name: Event,
    object: Object
}


abstract sig BaseOperation{
    name: Event,
    object: Object
// it will have more attributes than Condition later
}

abstract sig Connector{
    condition:  Condition,
    baseOperation:  BaseOperation,
}


sig Environment{
    ev : set Event
}

pred execute [u:Environment, u':Environment, r:Connector] {
          some e: u.ev | {
          e = r.condition.name =>    
              u'.ev = u.ev + r.baseOperation.name
          else
              u'.ev = u.ev
      }
}

fact {
     all u:Environment-last, u':u.next, r:Connector {
         execute [u, u', r]
     }
}


sig Object1 extends Object{
}{
    name = "Object1 Object"
}

sig Object2 extends Object{
}{
    name = "Object2 Object"
}

sig Condition1 extends Condition{
}{
    name = Event1
    object = Object2
    object.serviceCode = 1
}

sig Operation1 extends BaseOperation{
}{
    name = Event2
    object = Object1
    object.serviceCode = 1
}


sig Operation2 extends BaseOperation{
}{
    name = Event3
    object = Object1
    object.serviceCode = 0
}

one sig Connector1 extends Connector{
}{
    condition = Condition1
    baseOperation = Operation1

}

one sig Connector2  extends Connector{
}{
    condition = Condition1
    baseOperation = Operation2
}

fact {
     Event3 !in first.ev &&
    Event2 !in first.ev
}

run {Event1 in last.ev} for 10
```

The above code works fine when I have only one operation link to one object. I have attached the diagram for it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18p423cu-KKXk_vlFr0IfKYpAYGpw9OAW/view?usp=sharing) . Whenever there is more than one operation, then alloy fails to find an instance. Need help on designing alloy code for achieving my goal.

Another possible approach might be- instead of one service code, we may have a list of service code. Considering timestamp along with each service code. Then when need to find out the latest service code. We can take the service code of max timestamp. But I am not sure how to design this in alloy.

Comment: It would help if you tried to make the problem a lot smaller. (That said, my intuition says that your trace should not use all r:Connector, I assume this should be some r:Connector but I do not have time to explore your model since it is rather large.)

Comment: To sum up, the main problem that I am facing is I want to update a service code for each of the object in every step. But I am not able to do that.

Comment: Clearly you're not able to do that. However, to find out what you're not getting I would need to spend some time on your model to figure out where you go wrong. Since you have the problem and my time is precious I think if you want to get help you should spend your time to make your problem a lot smaller so that I can see the problem quickly. Or of course wait if someone else is nicer than me or has more time. Even then, that would be a waste. Few people will be able to learn from the problem because the example is too big to understand where the core of your problem is.

Comment: OK sure I can do that. Some times people want to see the full code. That's why I put the complete code here.

Comment: Is it possible to get the current timestamp in alloy. So that I can add service code list to each object based on timestamp. And then write another predicate to check latest service code for that object?
And my plan is to add each service code to the service code list of the object using the following approach: ```object.servicecodelist.servicecode = object.servicecodelist.servicecode + 1```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at Daniel Jackson's book. Alloy is not a programming language with mutable assignments. It is basically a rule engine over relations that can generate an *instance*, a set of relations matching those rules. This means that if you need mutable assignments then you need a way to represent the mutable state over time in a relation. There are two ways:

- `Time` – Make each field have a column with `Time`, where `Time` is ordered. I find this quite cumbersome. The [Electrum](https://github.com/haslab/Electrum) project made this easier by providing a `var` keyword that then maintains the `Time` column for you.
- `Trace` – Instead of associating each field with a `Time`, you can also place the associations in a *state* `sig` that is ordered. That relation then shows how the values change over time.

The key problem is that your problem description is almost completely disconnected from the specification. You talk about *Service* and then later *Operation*, are they the same?  Where do `Event` and `Connector` come in? They are never mentioned in your problem description?

Let's take it one by one:

> I want to change the *service code* of an *object*

```
   open util/ordering[Environment]

   sig Object {}
   enum ServiceCode { _1, _2 }

   sig Environment {
      object    : Object -> ServiceCode
   }
```

In general, you do not want to use Ints for things like Service Code since they tend to blow up the state space.

The `Environment` is our *state*. We want to execute one *Service* per Environment atom.

> ... whenever there has been any *service* operated upon it.

```
   sig Service {
    serviceCode : ServiceCode
   }

   pred execute[ e, e' : Environment, o : Object, s : Service ] {
    e'.object = e.object ++ o -> s.serviceCode       
   }
```

> Suppose, I have an *Operation* whenever that applies to an *Object*,

It is not clear what you mean with *Operation*, I assume this is the earlier *Service*?

> ... the *Service Code* of that *Object* will be 1 and again when 
>   another *Operation* executes then the *ServiceCode* will be 2. 
>   I want to save the latest service code to each object. Unfortunately,

```
  pred trace {
    no first.object
    all t : Environment-last, t':t.next {
           some o: Object, s : Service {
           execute[t,t', o, s]
        }
    }
  }

  run trace
```

In the table view this gives you:

```
┌────────────────┐
│this/ServiceCode│
├────────────────┤
│_1⁰             │
├────────────────┤
│_2⁰             │
└────────────────┘

┌───────────┐
│this/Object│
├───────────┤
│Object⁰    │
├───────────┤
│Object¹    │
└───────────┘

┌────────────┬───────────┐
│this/Service│serviceCode│
├────────────┼───────────┤
│Service⁰    │_2⁰        │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│Service¹    │_2⁰        │
├────────────┼───────────┤
│Service²    │_1⁰        │
└────────────┴───────────┘

┌────────────────┬───────────┐
│this/Environment│object     │
├────────────────┼───────────┤
│Environment⁰    │           │
├────────────────┼───────┬───┤
│Environment¹    │Object¹│_2⁰│
├────────────────┼───────┼───┤
│Environment²    │Object⁰│_1⁰│
│                ├───────┼───┤
│                │Object¹│_2⁰│
└────────────────┴───────┴───┘
```

When you use Alloy the first thing you should do is define the problem you want to specify in plain English. You then translate the concepts in this text to Alloy constructs. The goal of an Alloy spec is to make it read like prose.

Comment: thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help and detail comment.